# php custom exceptions

Tags: php, exception

I was wondering how would one go about writing custom exception handlers.

so that I can do something like

`throw new dbException($sql, $message);`

and have it output

> There was an error in your query
>   Message: {$message here}
>   Query:   {$sql here}
>   Line:    {line exception was thrown on}
>   File:    {file exception was thrown from}

but I also want to to catch eg syntax errors and parse errors (if possible)

Comment: You'll need a distinct handler for [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php) and [errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php). Parsing errors usually cannot be catched however.

Comment: Syntax/Parse errors are uncatchable, because they occur while php is being tokenized (by the lexer) and not in runtime. You can however, catch fatal errors (E_USER_ERROR) but it is your last chance to log any information before the script is being halted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can [extend the `Exception` class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) however you like. For custom exceptions, you might want to check out the post:

- [PHP 5 OOP: Delegation and Custom Exceptions](http://www.developer.com/lang/php/article.php/3608266/PHP-5-OOP-Delegation-and-Custom-Exceptions.htm)

You should also find this thread useful:

- [Custom Exception Messages: Best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628408/custom-exception-messages-best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, you should be able to [extend PHP's `Exception` class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use just write your own exception class derived from the standard base exception? See [extending exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) manual.