# CodeIgniter and throwing exceptions

Tags: php, exception, codeigniter, error-handling

I recently handed in a project for school which I built in CodeIgniter. I had to present it to my teacher and when asked how I handled certain errors, he told me to throw exceptions to intercept things a lot earlier in the chain of events.

I have learnt how to throw exceptions and how to use `try...catch` blocks to uh, catch and handle them but somehow, when I started using CodeIgniter, I forgot all about them and didn't really use exceptions anymore.

Instead, I just handled my errors 'manually', for lack of a better word: I'd use `TRUE`and `FALSE` boolean values to check if, for example, a query executed properly, and I would use the returned boolean to handle the result of the query. If `TRUE`, I'd go ahead and do my stuff, if `FALSE` I'd 'manually' throw an error message. The project was very AJAX-dependent and the error messages would pop up in quite a fancy way, dropping down from the top of the page; not sure if this is possible when I throw an exception with `throw new Exception`? I know that this basically stops the code from executing when the exception is thrown, so wouldn't that break things somehow?

I also seem to remember reading somewhere that throwing exceptions isn't the best practice ever but I can't find the source of this anymore and I'm not quite sure if this is the case; after all, we did learn how to use them in class and I like to believe we learn best practices there, haha.

If necessary, I could go back and try to find the piece of code where he pointed out that I should've thrown an exception. However, for now, I'm just wondering whether or not I should use exceptions in my code or handle things manually. What are the best practices regarding this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly of interest, fairly good answer here: [Why and how would you use Exceptions in this sample PHP code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935490/935520#935520)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just FYI, I don't use exceptions in CodeIgniter tho I'm using them a lot in Kohana, just because the framework throws them and everything is designed to work with exceptions unlike CodeIgniter. Using exceptions is a good practice providing all your classes/framework are designed to work with them.

I don't (really, DON'T) want to enter in framework comparison discussions, but I need to compare two pieces of code to clarify your question, one piece from CI2 and another from Kohana 3 (it born as a branch of CI with better object oriented implementation).

You'll see this CI2 code...

```
try
{
    $result = $this->db->insert('entries', $this->input->post());

    // This is not useful.
    if ( ! $result)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

It's not very useful. Compare with this Kohana 3 code:

```
try
{
    $entry = ORM::factory('blog');
    $entry->values(Request::current()->post());
    $entry->save();
}
catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
{
    Session::instance()->set('form_errors', $e->errors(TRUE));
}
```

You'll see this is useful, you don't throw the exception, it's thrown by the class that handles the record saving and `$e->errors` has all the validation errors. When everything is designed to work with exceptions, you can be sure it's a good practice and a very convenient one. But it's not the case of CI2, so maybe I should say go ahead without using exceptions.

---

### A possible approach to exceptions in CI...

```
try
{
    $this->load->model('blog');
    $this->blog->save_entry($this->input->post());   // Handle validation inside the model with the Form_validation library
}
catch (Validation_Exception $e)   // You throwed your custom exception with the failed validation information
{
    // Do something with your custom exception like the kohana example
    $this->session->set('form_errors', $e->errors());
}
```

I hope everything is understandable and maybe there's someone with another interesting opinion and a more efficient implementation. Bye.

Comment: So in the 'possible approach for CI', you basically throw a custom exception in the model? I think I understand; your explanation makes a lot of sense, especially when I see the comparison with Kohana. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, inside the model you check, for example, if the record insertion failed and then throw your custom exception with the validation errors in it. There's a question about custom exceptions in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008965/php-custom-exceptions

Comment: I think the best practice would be : #1 always and only throw exceptions in models #2 always and only try/catch them in controllers. This way, everything works fine and fluently.